Understanding notation for Organ Registration
I try to rearrange the organ part of Maurice Duruflé's own orchestral reduction of his Requiem (ca. mid 20th century), but I struggle to understand some specifics of his organ notations (see screen shots below):

What do "R", "G", "G.R.", sometimes "m.g." mean?
At one location it says "G. _4" that might be a registration?

Regarding organ registration: Any tip where I can practice / listen to the different sounds, it says for example: Flute, Bourdon, Principal, Gambe, Voix celeste, Cromorne, Fonds et Anches, Mixtures, etc. since I can't imagine the sound when arranging for my instrument (accordion)?
Perhaps there is a "organ for dummies" website somewhere?
Thanks in advance, Dostl_ba


Introit Page 1:


Introit Page 5:


Kyrie Page 5:




I add this to my own question (after coming back to my arrengement)
There is a nice organ glossary in german and french wikipedia, perhaps someone wants to translate this to the english wikipedia:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgel-Glossar

@GratefulDisciple

Well, a glossary of French organ terms and abbreviations sure isn't coming up in Google searches! Lots of old and poorly designed pages offer partial info. This one: https://organhistoricalsociety.org/OrganHistory/begin.htm seems pretty good, on the left select "geographical tour" then "France", then browse the pages, especially "17th 18th century registration".

If you are using this online score https://www.sonomabach.org/uploads/2/2/5/6/22562520/159784280-durufle-requiem-score.pdf I think the scan may have skipped pages giving the stops and abbreviations.

Please post a representative image and information on the edition you're using. It would also help to know which movement/measures.

refined the question and added images. @MichaelCurtis I have a different version of that score. And please note that the composer is from the 20th century.

Ah well, a bit of googling still helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vingt-quatre_pi%C3%A8ces_en_style_libre gives part of an answer, but still I do not udnerstand what it means being no organ player: "Two immediately adjacent initials (G. R.) indicate that the grand organ is coupled to the récit, or swell; the initial G. indicates that this keyboard is separated from the swell. Same observation for the initials placed next to the name Ped. They indicate with which keyboard the pedal is coupled."

@Bastl, I too suspected G.R. meant grande recit, but I was not really sure. I'm glad you eventually got a good answer from Phoog. And that wiki page you found is very helpful.

@AndyBonner For some reason, I wasn't alerted, maybe because I didn't post any comment on this Q.  I was collecting resources to answer it (even found a video on the registration of this specific piece), but phoog beat me to it.  I'll just add comment on his answer.

Related question.

Some of these indicate organ divisions, each corresponding to a manual in the organ console.  G is "grand orgue" (in English, "great") and R is "récit" (in English, "swell") -- a set of pipes enclosed in a box with louvers that control the volume by their opening and closing.  G.R. indicates that the récit should be coupled to the grand, so the organist will play on the grand manual, and pipes from both divisions will sound.
The vertical brackets show which notes each indication concerns.
M.g. is not a registration instruction.  It stands for "main gauche," which means "left hand."
Ped _ flûtes 8 means (assuming the underscore is actually a minus sign) "Pedal, remove flute stops, 8 foot."  (Flue pipes are basically fipple flutes, similar to a recorder; each stop's octave is indicated by the length, nominally, of the C2 pipe; 8 feet is notated pitch; 16 ft is an octave lower; 4 ft is an octave higher, etc.)  Similarly, R + Fonds 8 means "récit, add 8 foot flue stops."  Péd G. R. means "couple the great and swell to the pedal."  "G. _4" would mean "turn off the 4-foot stops on tbe grand orgue."
Anches (English: "reeds") have metallic tongues that vibrate in the air stream, similar to a harmonica or indeed an accordion.  Mixtures are groups of pipes tuned to harmonics of the nominal pitch, so for example the A2 key might open a pipe sounding at 550 Hz and another at 660 Hz.  Bourdon pipes are stopped flue pipes: they sound an octave lower than they would if open, and they have only odd harmonics.  So R. Fonds et Anches 8-4, Mixtures means "récit, flue and reed stops, 8 and 4 feet, with mixtures," and _G. Fonds 8-4, Bourdon 16" means "grand orgue, flue stops, 8 and 4 feet and bourdon 16 feet."
What does this all mean, though?  First, I notice that you didn't highlight the registration given at the beginning of the introit.  Obviously this is important!  Without it, an instruction such as "remove the 8-foot flutes" makes little sense.  More generally, you can start by recognizing the significance of the octave indications (16, 8, 4, etc.), and that that anches indicates a richer, more complex tone with more upper harmonics, and mixtures even more so.  Obviously all of the stops on an accordion are reed stops, but you would want to use the least reedy ones for the flue stops and lusher combinations for e.g. rehearsal 16 of the Kyrie.  Adding stops not only changes the sound quality, of course, but also the volume.  And at the opening of the introit, where the left hand is playing the swell (marked piano, so presumably closed) and the right hand plays the great coupled to the swell, the right-hand part will be significantly louder than the left-hand part.
Duruflé made two other versions of this piece, one for full orchestra and one for reduced orchestra with organ, so these orchestrations can also be a good source of inspiration for your own registration.
As to learning the sounds of individual organ stops, keep in mind that they varied somewhat over the centuries.  Probably the best thing to do would be to befriend an organist or otherwise arrange some practice time on an actual pipe organ.  Failing that, listen to as many different recordings as you can by famous organists of this piece and any other for which you can find the score, and listen for the differences in their registration choices.
Finally, as with any transcription or indeed any performance, the spirit of the law is more important than the letter.  Don't play a crescendo before rehearsal 16 because Duruflé wrote cresc ... molto cresc.  Don't add a 16-foot stop at 16 because Duruflé said to.  Instead, ask yourself why Duruflé gave these instructions and how you can realize the music most effectively.  The crescendo has a purpose; adding the 16-foot stop has a purpose.  Yes, you should start by adding the lower octave at that point on your accordion if it is feasible, but if it sounds too muddy or does not support the formal inflection point of the bass entrance for some reason, you should explore other options.

Wow! Thank you! I'm posting questions to various forums since the beginning of my (IT) carreer in the late 90s - but I never got such an educated and extensive answer to my questions as here. You fully answer nearly all my questions, even some of those that are still on my mind :-) Especially your notes on "interpretation" are valuable - I feel the same but without (educated) feedback or teachers it is hard to improve. I'd love to share the results with you once done.

and btw I am not arranging for one instrument but for an ensemble of 4 "voices" plus a bass-accordion. This makes it a bit easier to reflect the intentions as far as I get them. And in order to avoid misinterpretations or even "recomposition" I would like to stay close to the text ... I would "change" something only if absolutely necessary or definitely bound to the instrument (and not the music). When changing sth then of course in such a way that the intention / purpose is reflected as good as possible.

@Bastl thanks for your kind remarks. They prompt me to a small disclaimer, though: I am not an organist (and I know even less about accordions!). An organist would have much more to say about this than I can. I would also like to add, in response to your mention of "recomposition," that registration directions are the sort of thing that will require flexibility even when playing the piece on different organs: the organist must decide what the indications mean and how to realize the musical intention on the instrument they're using; in that respect, the same as you will do with the accordions.

@Bastl I found a lecture for conductors of Duruflé's Requiem which includes a special guest organist who gave tips on organ registrations, esp. to adapt Duruflé's instructions to the organ that the organist has at her disposal (which may not be a French 19th/20th romantic organ).  There are little snippets of demo so you can hear the sound as well.  The full score is here to follow along.

@Bastl Organ registrations come in regional families with discernable historical development, so having a sense of the historical background of each voice, the physics of different type of pipes, and how each division was started are very important.  You can start with this Encyclopedia Britannica article.  For a freely available treatise, this 1919 book is one good resource, which includes some notation.

But that book is rather lacking on French organ, so I found these 3 articles on Understanding the French Organ useful: part 1, part 2, part 3.

@Bastl The 1964 book Pipe Organ Registration by Jack Goode has a whole chapter (#16) on French Organ Music which is more readable, starting on page 68 to page 88.  It covers registration for playing Romantic French organ music by Franck, Widor, Vierne, Langlais, and Messiaen.  Though not specifically for Duruflé, I think all your questions are answered here; list of registration notation abbreviation provided on pages 86-88.

These look a bit like organ stops. Perhaps G for "great" or "grande." I'm not sure about R.
https://organhistoricalsociety.org/OrganHistory/history/hist026.htm

The R is then probably the Recit and the point is that these sets of pipes are coupled or not.

Duruflé being a 20th-century composer (and organist), that site's pages on Cavaillé-Coll and the French romantic organ are the ones to read, not the page linked here.
